# How to simplify the use of viewmodel/model with many properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I am working on an application for remote device management. Each device has equal set of near two hundred parameters. I think each device will be represented by a DeviceModel and DeviceViewModel classes. As a result of a large number of device parameters the DeviceModel and the DeviceViewModel are very cumbersome. Besides, such a number of INPC properties is probably not good in terms of performance.

So. It's OK to have ViewModel with so large number of properties? Will this impact on performance or may be it is not so much? If it's not good, is there any approaches to solving this problem?

**EDIT**
To narrow down the question (and not confuse you with device manager) I edited it.

Comment: Careful with breaking objects in to smaller objects.  This can lead to confusion for developers who have to figure out what object to use when their existence was just to cut the method-count down!

Comment: apart from "yes, but ..." answers, what kind of response are you expecting. The question is too broad I fear.

Comment: Are you using an automated mapping framework, as that would help?

Comment: Agree with Jodrell, but I would create a Dictionary object to hold all unique properties of different devices it is easy for iterating on property and you can still read property like an array. Plus you can load profile of device with say a json string or a textfile such as ini file for device, to load it's property in your object.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have a device manager "object" but let devices assume the responsability of reporting / modifying their parameters ? If a device has a lot of parameters, its expected that the device's model also have a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no cure if you are not willing (or able) to modify the design of your model.

That said, you can design your model anyway you want. You don't have to create a class per device for example.

The model doesn't have to reflect the physical model (devices and hundreds of parameters), it can be a logical abstraction which helps you and potentially other developers deal with the problem domain.

Try to identify parameters of a device which are somehow related and group them in a class. You can then aggregate these "parameter group" classes from a "device" class.

Also, don't include unused parameters in your model, they will only clutter your design and increase maintenance cost. Adding them later should be no problem.

Well, it was a broad question... hope this helps!

Comment: OK, let's say I will break the `DeviceModel` into several smaller parts (i.e. `DeviceSubmodel1`...`DeviceSubmodelN`). I think it's a good idea. But what to do with `DeviceViewModel`?

Comment: @Menzoda Well, that depends. Typically you are going to have a view for each part of your model and not clump everything together in a single view. It is simplest that you divide your `DeviceViewModel` into (`DeviceSubViewModel1` ... `DeviceSubViewModelN`) and do the same with your view classes. You should pick meaningful names though.

Answer (score 0):

if your concern is bandwidth concerning the two hundreds of properties find a default value for each property and do not include that property in the transport (serialization).

That will greatly reduce each message byte count.

As a side note, WPF uses a similar approach for each instance: each class has a static dictionary of `<property, default value>`